# What types of software vulnerabilities are out there?

Tags: exploit, known-vulnerabilities, vulnerability

I have search a lot in the internet and I didn't find anything that is directly answer my question. What type of vulnerabilities are out there. I mean vulnerabilities like buffer overrun, not like XSS or SQLi etc. 
Here is a short list of vulnerabilities I know that exist:

1. Buffer overruns(stack and heap)
2. Integer overflow
3. Format string vulnerability
4. Access Control Problems

Could anybody add something to this list?

Comment: While Gumbo's answer is excellent, this question is actually incredibly broad. Also, the second part of your question is explicitly off topic here, so I have removed it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most comprehensible dictionary of software weaknesses is the [Common Weakness Enumeration (CWE)](https://cwe.mitre.org/).

The [view *Development Concepts (CWE-699)*](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/graphs/699.html) may be a good starting point for you:

> This view organizes weaknesses around concepts that are frequently used or encountered in software development. Accordingly, this view can align closely with the perspectives of developers, educators, and assessment vendors.

There are also [graphical depictions of CWE](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/pdfs.html), which shows relations of weaknesses in a directed graph, e. g., the [graphical depiction of CWE-699](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/pdf/699_abstraction_colors.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is too broad, but OWASP is probably the closest thing to what you're asking: https://www.owasp.org

Their "Top 10" threat list: [https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project#tab=OWASP_Top_10_for_2013](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project#tab=OWASP_Top_10_for_2013)

Their cheat sheets: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cheat_Sheets

Developers guide: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_Table_of_Contents

Comment: The question isn't broad. I'm asking only for the names of the most common vulnerabilities in the software code. OWASP is about WEB APPLICATIONS, I said that I'm not asking about XSS and SQLi etc..

Comment: OWASP covers these things: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Buffer_Overflows search on that guide table of content page. Plus, SQLi can easily apply to traditional desktop applications.